# Creating and comparing class instances without variable assignment in python

Tags: oop, instance

While "playing" with OOP paradigm in Python I encountered with some misunderstanding. 
Let's see some small example:

```
class A(object):
    pass

print id(A()), id(A())    # 139865221604432 139865221604432
print id(A()) == id(A())  # True
print A() is A()          # False
a1 = A()                  
print id(a1)              # 139865221604432
a2 = A()
print id(a2)              # 139865220638096
```

So the question is why the id number for the first print example is the same for both instances. As we take a look at `A() is A()` we can see that all is 'ok' and the result is False. Not sure, but can it be dealing with garbage collection?

Another example:

```
class B(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.msg = 'Some default message'
        print id(self)

    def do_smth(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg

    def get_msg(self):
        return self.msg
```

Then we have two cases.

**1st:**

```
B().do_smth(B().get_msg() + ' add')
```

**2nd**

```
b = B()
b.do_smth(b.get_msg() + ' add')
```

As far as I understand the second approach is much more preferable, because we do not create two instances like in the first one. But are there any interesting cases when we can meet 1st approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) for the `id` function...

> Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.

When you do

```
print id(A()), id(A())
```

it prints the same id for each object because the first object has gone out of scope. Each instance of `A` which you've created exists only as long as the call to id takes. Once the variable goes out of scope it can be collected and its id reused. As soon as you assign the object to a variable that it cannot be reused until the variable goes out of scope.

In your second example the reason that the second form would be preferred over the first is that usually object instances differ in their state. Your first form only really works because all instances of `B` have the same values - and that's an unusual property for a class. It's worth noting, however, that it's usually not best OO practice to ask an object for a piece of data and then hand that data back to the object as a method argument.